# Accessing saved obstacle grid map within my program

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I create an obstacle grid map using gmapping and my pr2 in gazebo, how do I make that map available to my code. If I provide the map as a service using: rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml, can I still subscribe to the /map topic to access it within my program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53009/accessing-saved-obstacle-grid-map-within-my-program/) by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your program you can use either the service or the topic that map_server provides.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1